# How do I know if is in silent mode?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I am developing an App in Corona-SDK and I need to know if smartphone is in silent mode. But I didn't find nothing about this in documentation.

Comment: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/audio/getVolume.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer in native android, i don`t know if it the same syntax in corona
Anyway here is my answer:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        switch (am.getRingerMode()) {

            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:

                break;
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:

                break;

            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:

                break;
        }*
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in the free Corona SDK and you need the enterprise version to check that.